# FOSUser's register form customized: datas not saved in DB

Tags: php, forms, symfony, fosuserbundle

I try to custom the registration form of FOSUserBundle for the first time, following [the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_forms.html) but when I submit the form, there is an error message that ask me to "enter the firstname" even when the field is not blank.

I am mistaking something and I don't know what. Here is my code:

`src/AppBundle/Entity/User.php`:

```html
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
     protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="firstname", type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please enter your first name.", groups={"Registration", "Profile"})
     * @Assert\Length(
     *     min=3,
     *     max=255,
     *     minMessage="The name is too short.",
     *     maxMessage="The name is too long.",
     *     groups={"Registration", "Profile"}
     * )
     */
     protected $firstname;

        // ...

     public function getFirstname()
     {
         return $this->firstname;
     }
 
     public function setFirstname($firstname)
     {
         $this->$firstname = $firstname;
     }

        // ...
}
```

`src/AppBundle/Form/RegistrationType.php`:

```php
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class RegistrationType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('firstname', null, array(
            'label' => false,
            'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle',
            'attr' => array(
                'placeholder' => 'form.firstname'
                )
            ));
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType';
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'app_user_registration';
    }
}
```

My `app/config/services.yml` and `app/config/config.yml` are exactly the same as in the documentation.

What did I do wrong ?
Thanks.

**EDIT:**

After some researches, it looks like the form doesn't fill well the `User` entity. If my `firstname` field is filled with `Jason` (for example), it will add a key to the Entity named `Jason` and filled with `Jason` and `firstname` will be `null`.

BUT, if the field is filled with `firstname` SO the `firstname` key will be filled with `firstname` and it will be saved into the DB:[image: If it is filled with "Jason"][image: If it is filled with "firstname"]

Answer (score 1):

Try to point the validation group by force. In your RegistrationType class you can override the method configureOptions:

```
    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
     public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
     {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class'            => 'AppBundle\Entity\User', // not required
        'csrf_protection'       => true, // not required
        'validation'            => true, // not required
        'validation_groups'     => ['Registration', 'Profile'], // try this! 
        ));
     }
```

Comment: I don't have any classe name setDefaults in my `RegistrationType` class.
Maybe because i use symfony 3?

Comment: I'm sorry. I've already corrected the answer. My typo. method called `configureOptions()`

Comment: I just try your suggestion and it doesn't work, sorry. With it, when I try to load the `/register` page, I have a `FatalErrorException`: 

`Compile Error: Declaration of AppBundle\Form\RegistrationType::configureOptions(AppBundle\Form\OptionsResolver $resolver) must be compatible with Symfony\Component\Form\FormTypeInterface::configureOptions(Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver $resolver)`

Comment: Add the use statement above the class declaration  -               
`use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;`

Comment: No more Exception but the problem still the same

Comment: You can add validation constraints inline. It's not write way, but we can figure out where the problem is hidden: 
`$builder->add('firstname', null, array(
               // ...
                'validation'            => true,
                'validation_groups'     => 'Registration',
                'constraints'           => array(new Valid()),
               //..
            ));`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151362/discussion-between-staskrak-and-lecintas).